# selecting and sorting "numeric columns names", created by a pivot_wider action

Tags: r, dplyr

I have a table of data created by pivot_wider.  The "names_from" are numbers which are now the column headers in the new table.  Would like to select the last column and arrange() descending.  The column names (years in this case) may change in number and name depending upon the size of the table being pivoted_wider.  I've tried using get() and paste0() to create the column name from the max() value of year, but get an error saying the column doesn't exist.

Code I tried:

```
        tmp <- pivot_wider(tmp, names_from = YR, values_from = Num_Deals) %>% 
            arrange(ends_with(paste0(max(YRS)))) 
        tmp
```

Here is the pivot_wider result I would like to sort, by the column with the latest year (2010, in this case):

## A tibble: 912 x 7

| name | `2005` | `2006` | `2007` | `2008` | `2009` | `2010` |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
|  |  |  |  |  |  |  |
| 1 Sierra Ventures | 5 | 4 | 2 | 2 | 2 | 2 |
| 2 Mayfield Fund | 4 | NA | 1 | NA | NA | 4 |
| 3 Focus Ventures | 4 | 1 | 2 | 1 | 2 | NA |

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There are most likely simpler solutions, but you can use:

```r
library(dplyr)

tmp %>% 
  arrange(desc(!!sym(as.character(max(as.integer(names(.)[grepl("\\d+", names(.))]))))))
```

This returns

```r
# A tibble: 3 x 7
  name            `2005` `2006` `2007` `2008` `2009` `2010`
  <chr>            <dbl>  <dbl>  <dbl>  <dbl>  <dbl>  <dbl>
1 Mayfield_Fund        4     NA      1     NA     NA      4
2 Sierra_Ventures      5      4      2      2      2      2
3 Focus_Ventures       4      1      2      1      2     NA
```

Comment: I tried it, but got a couple errors.  It said the !!! has been deprecated to !! only ... so I tried that and got the following:


>   tmp <- pivot_wider(tmp, names_from = YR, values_from = Num_Deals) %>% 
+     arrange(!!sym(as.character(max(names(.)[grepl("\\d+", names(.))]))))
Note: Using an external vector in selections is ambiguous.
i Use `all_of(YR)` instead of `YR` to silence this message.
i See <https://tidyselect.r-lib.org/reference/faq-external-vector.html>.
Error: Can't subset columns that don't exist.
x Location 2021 doesn't exist.
i There are only 7 columns.

Comment: And ... would like to sort by column with most recent year. `2010` in this case.

Comment: I fixed it as follows: changing as.characer to as.String seemed to make it all work .. also added "desc" to get descending order of max YR column.

tmp <- pivot_wider(tmp, names_from = YR, values_from = Num_Deals) %>% 
    arrange(desc(!!sym(as.String(max(names(.)[grepl("\\d+", names(.))])))))